# Filter to not Include Matched Values in Result Arrays

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a query where I first want to match find the list of matched users and then filter the matches out from the array of external users that was passed in so that I am left with users Id's that have not been matched yet.

Here is a the match Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // only match two users at a time.
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MatchSchema = new Schema({
    participants: [{
        type: String, ref: 'user'        
    }],
    blocked: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});
```

Here is the query with explanations:

```
db.getCollection('match').aggregate([
               { 
          '$match': {
               '$and': [       
                    { participants: "599f14855e9fcf95d0fe11a7" }, // the current user.
                    { participants: {'$in': [ "598461fcda5afa9e0d2a8a64","598461fcda5afa9e0d111111", "599f14855e9fcf95d0fe5555"] } } // array of external users that I want to check if the current user is matched with.
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            '$project': {
                'participants': 1
            }
        },
```

This returns the following result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c0d76e66dd407f5efe7112"),
    "participants" : [ 
        "599f14855e9fcf95d0fe11a7", 
        "599f14855e9fcf95d0fe5555"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c0d76e66dd407f5efe75ac"),
    "participants" : [ 
        "598461fcda5afa9e0d2a8a64", 
        "599f14855e9fcf95d0fe11a7"
    ]
}
```

what I want to do next it merge the participants array form both results into one array.

Then I want to take away the those matching items from the array of external users so that I am left with user id's that have not been matched yet.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's probably not the best example set of data given the line in your question: *"Then I want to take away the those matching items from the array of external users so that I am left with user id's that have not been matched yet."*. So what do you actually mean there? Does that mean that you are expecting to return the "unique list" from participants obtained from documents that matched the query, of which *"where not one of the parameters supplied in the query itself"*? So you supply a list of values to match, then you want every value returned **except** those supplied?

Comment: Basically I want to do is  1: pass in an array of users (array X) that might or might not be matched with the current user.  2: find the list of matched users.  3: remove the list of matched users from (array X).  4: return the list of unique users that have not been matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want those results in the array, then [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) them out.

Either by building the conditions with [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) ( aggregation logical version ):

```
var currentUser = "599f14855e9fcf95d0fe11a7",
    matchingUsers = [ 
      "598461fcda5afa9e0d2a8a64",
      "598461fcda5afa9e0d111111",
      "599f14855e9fcf95d0fe5555"
    ],
    combined = [currentUser, ...matchingUsers];

db.getCollection('match').aggregate([
  { '$match': {
    'participants': { '$eq': currentUser, '$in': matchingUsers }
  }},
  { '$project': {
    'participants': {
      '$filter': {
        'input': '$participants',
        'as': 'p',
        'cond': {
          '$not': {
            '$or': combined.map(c =>({ '$eq': [ c, '$$p' ] }))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Or use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) ( again the aggregation version ) if you have MongoDB 3.4 which supports it:

```
db.getCollection('match').aggregate([
  { '$match': {
    'participants': { '$eq': currentUser, '$in': matchingUsers }
  }},
  { '$project': {
    'participants': {
      '$filter': {
        'input': '$participants',
        'as': 'p',
        'cond': {
          '$not': {
            '$in': ['$p', combined ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

It really does not matter. It's just the difference of using JavaScript to build the expression before the pipeline is sent or letting a supported pipeline operator do the array comparison where it is actually supported.

Note you can also write the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) a bit more efficiently by using an "implicit" form of `$and`, as is shown.

> Also note you have a problem in your schema definition ( but not related to this particular query ). You cannot use a "ref" to another collection as `String` in one collection where it is going to be `ObjectId` ( the default for `_id`, and presumed of the hex values obtained ) in the other. This mismatch means `.populate()` or `$lookup` functions cannot work. So you really should correct the types.
>
> Unrelated to this. But something you need to fix as a priority.